# argument_name and an argument_value in a named argument?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters, arguments

Recently I have been covering the topic about arguments in C# in regards to a method. While reading [Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1162-argument-lists) I came across the following excerpt which states:

> An argument_list consists of one or more arguments, separated by commas. Each argument consists of an optional argument_name followed by an argument_value. An argument with an argument_name is referred to as a named argument, whereas an argument without an argument_name is a positional argument.

Code Example - Positional Arguments:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        // two positional arguments in the argument-list
        CustomStaticMethod(4, "hello"); 
    }

    public static void CustomStaticMethod(int num, string word)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

Code Example - Named Arguments:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        // two named arguments in the argument-list
        CustomStaticMethod(word: "hello", num: 4);
    }

    public static void CustomStaticMethod(int num, string word)
    {
        // ...
    }
```

What does the C# documentation excerpt mean by an **argument_name** and **argument_value** in regards to a named argument?

Comment: From that document *"A named argument corresponds to the parameter of the same name in the parameter list."* so `argument_name` represents the name in the corresponding argument list of the actual called method.

Comment: Hi @Charlieface thanks for the input. But then what does argument_value represent? The thing that comes after the colon ( : ) in a named argument?

Comment: I would have thought that's quite obvious: the argument being passed. Look at the grammar: positional parameters and named parameters both have `argument_value`, the only difference is `argument_name`. The grammar says `argument_value : expression | 'ref' variable_reference | 'out' variable_reference` which I think makes it clear

Comment: @Charlieface Because of MasterWil's answer I understand what you mean by **argument_value : expression | 'ref' variable_reference | 'out' variable_reference** but it may confuse other users due to the colon you included. Since the format/setup of a named argument consists of a colon character. According to MasterWil the format/setup of a named argument goes as follows **argument name: argument_value**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code: `CustomStaticMethod(word: "hello", num: 4);`

When you supply an argument in `<name>: <value>` format, this argument is a `named argument`.

Where:

- `word` is argument name,
- `"hello"` is argument value.

Now consider this case:

```
public static void CustomStaticMethod(string foo, int num, string bar) { 
    //...
}
```

You can mix positional argument and named argument like this:

```
public static void Main() {
    CustomStaticMethod(bar: "hello", 4, foo: "world"); 
}
```

Using named argument let you supply arguments without memorise the exact position of each argument. This is especially useful if the method to call has a long parameter list.

For more information you can read from the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments).